# Share link preview on whatsapp contain google tag manager code

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-tag-manager, whatsapp

[Code appears to WhatsApp share link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yRiKP.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this? When I share a website link on WhatsApp, there is a code that includes on preview of the link on WhatsApp. Because it can interfere with the preview share link. The photo of the problem is on the link.

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-W7KRK8S');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

I use google tag manager code above, and the code appears to the whatsapp share link preview like the picture that i attach by the link above.

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved. How is this problem related to PHP?

Comment: If you don't specify the relevant meta data (see duplicate), then Facebook / WhatsApp will try to extract relevant content for a short description from the page content on its own, but that doesn't always work well.